# How to set a particular value selected when data is coming from an API

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown list:-

```
<label>User Code:</label>
<select ng-options="c as c.User for c in userList"
    ng-model="selectedUser" id="search3">
</select>
```

The data in this dropdown is coming from an API. My directive code:-

```
scope.getAllPeriodicities = function(){
    scope.userList = [];
    ApiServices.getAllPeriodicities().then(function (response) {
        scope.userList = response.data;
    });
}

scope.getAllPeriodicities();
```

There is an User Code:-`SS1234`. I want this user to be selected whenever the page loads. I am thinking of using `selected` attribute but not sure how to use it on the fetched data.

Comment: what is the scope.userList data?

Comment: You don't need to use the `selected` attribute, just set `$scope.selectedUser` to be equal to the item you want in your list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default value in ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993468/how-to-set-default-value-in-ng-options)

Answer (score 1):

```
scope.getAllPeriodicities = function(){
  scope.userList = [];
    ApiServices.getAllPeriodicities().then(function (response) {
       scope.userList = response.data;
       scope.selectedUser = "SS1234";
   });
}
scope.getAllPeriodicities();
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your default value to the `ng-model` by using `ng-init` or `ng-value`

```
<select ng-options="c as c.User for c in userList" ng-model="selectedUser" 
 id="search3" ng-value={{selectedUser = 'SS1234'}}></select>
```

//or

```
<select ng-options="c as c.User for c in userList" ng-model="selectedUser" 
 id="search3" ng-init="selectedUser = 'SS1234'"></select>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this select the first option from the returned promise?

Comment: that's why I have mentioned to use `ng-init`

Answer (score 1):

simply asign, `scope.selectedUser="SS1234"` user you want.

```
scope.userList = response.data;
scope.selectedUser = scope.userList[0].User /* here i choose 0th index of user. you can change as you want */
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller add,

```
$scope.selectedUser = 'SS1234';
```