# How to print value from an array in angular js

Tags: php, angularjs

I have select option code:

```
<select ng-init="loadHouse()" name="house" ng-model="house" class="form-control">  
 <option value="">Select House</option>  
 <option ng-repeat="house in houses" value="{{house.hid}}">{{house.hname}}</option>  
</select>
```

Script:

```
$scope.loadHouse = function(){
 $http.get("Unity/load_house.php")  
 .then(function(data){
  $scope.houses = data;  
  console.log(data);
 })  
}
```

And load_house.php

```
include('../config/config.php');
require 'model/model.unity.php';
$insertHouse = loadHouses();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($insertHouse)){  
  $output[] = $row;  
}  
echo json_encode($output);
```

It seems to work and I am able to print data inside console. But inside option its empty:

[image]

What can be the problem?

**EDIT**
Here is console data:

[image]

Comment: how does your array look like console.log(data);

Comment: We would have to see what your response is, or how the house-object looks like, to be able to help you.

Comment: @Sajeetharan please see edit.

Comment: @zeropublix I edited the question.

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy btw instead of using an `ng-repeat` on your `<option>` check out `ng-options`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use data.data

```
$scope.loadHouse = function(){
 $http.get("Unity/load_house.php")  
 .then(function(data){
  $scope.houses = data.data;  
  console.log(data);
 })  
}
```

also use ng-options instead of ng-repeat as follows

```
<select ng-options="item as item.hcolor for item in houses" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

Comment: im getting error when i use ng-options. Here is an error: `angular.js:14525 Error: [$compile:ctreq]` With ng-repeat its fine

Comment: that was just a suggestion

Comment: I found the problem. Thank you for help

Comment: How to add option "select House" in it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993468/how-to-set-default-value-in-ng-options

Comment: If this is not set in 0 index of options array!

Answer (score 0):

you should define scope of `houses`, outside of loadHouse function
try this.

```
$scope.houses = [];
$scope.loadHouse = function(){
  $http.get("Unity/load_house.php")  
   .then(function(data){
     $scope.houses = data;  
     console.log(data);
   })  
}
```

and your ng-model of `select` should different then `ng-repeat` local scope of `house`, try this

```
ng-repeat="_house in houses"
```