# Display label displayed in options as the title of select

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How to show `option.Brand.Name` as the title of the `select` field without using `java script` and changing the `ng-model`?

```
<select ng-model="detail.BrandId" title="" class="form-control" disabled>
    <option ng-repeat="option in mainCtrl.products" ng-selected="option.Id === detail.ProductId" ng-value="option.BrandId">{{option.Brand.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Shaheryar.Akram Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work on my end.

Comment: just use ng-attr-title="{{detail. Brand.Name}}"

Comment: @minaalfy Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to change the ng-model to 'detail.Brand'

Comment: Exactly why are you trying to accomplish this?  This sounds like poor design more than anything.

Comment: The select field above is one of the many fields in a table due to the space, user would not be able to view the 'Brand.Name' right away and they would need to refresh to be able to view it by tooltip

Comment: Can you please provide records of `mainCtrl.products` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### AngularJS and select-options

Try using `ng-options` [AngularJS **ngOptions** directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) within `select` element itself. Then you don't need to add each `option` element yourself using `ng-repeat`.

### Clarification

The **title**-attribute belongs to the **select**-element and will show if you hover over the select. You would like the title to reveal the **current selected option**? Did I understand you correctly?

> How to show `option.Brand.Name` as the `title` of the `select` field

Curious, where this `detail.ProductId` comes from? Is the brand preselected by product-id (see your code)?

> ng-selected="option.Id === detail.ProductId"

### Solution space

Your requirements/restrictions are:

- **without using JavaScript** (maybe because you can't change the sources)
- **without changing the ng-model** (because you need there only the `BrandId` for some database-reasons)

So since the **title** of the select-element has no access to the options inside, the only way to set it is depending on the current selection, i.e. your `detail.BrandId`. So the `title` can only set dynamically (depending on the current selection) by using standard-angularJS means, as:

- `{{ expression }}` [expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)
- `{{ expression | filter }}` [array-filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

### Expected behavior

The only scope-variable changed by selecting is specified within select's `ng-model` as `detail.BrandId`. This will be set when user selects an `option` to its property `BrandId`. When user selects between options they will be visible with ther `BrandName` as label. After selection this `BrandName` (label of the option) should be shown as **title** of the entire select element.

So we need to get from `detail.BrandId` (*selected* ng-model) to related options `BrandName` (as this should show as title).

### Possible Solution

Only way is to use standard angular expressions/filters/array-indexing to get the whole option by the selected `detail.BrandId` (ng-model)

Then we can *lookup* the `option.BrandName` by this *equation* after selected `detail.BrandId === option.BrandId`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.products = [
    {Id: 0, name: 'Watson', brandId: 1, brandName:"IBM"},
    {Id: 1, name: 'DB2', brandId: 1, brandName:"IBM"},
    {Id: 2, name: 'Windows', brandId: 2, brandName: "Microsoft"},
    {Id: 3, name: 'Office', brandId: 2, brandName: "Microsoft"}
  ];
  $scope.detail = { ProductId: 3, BrandId: null };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body data-ng-app="app" data-ng-controller="mainCtrl">
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
   <th>Product Id</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Choose Brand</th><th>Brand Id</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{detail.ProductId}}</td>
          <td>{{ (products | filter: {Id: detail.ProductId})[0].name }}</td>
          <td>
            <select class="form-control"
             ng-model="detail.BrandId" 
             ng-init="detail.BrandId = (products | filter: {Id: detail.ProductId})[0].brandId"
             ng-options="o.brandId as ('['+ o.Id +'] '+ o.name +' : '+ o.brandName  +' ('+ o.brandId +')') for o in products"
             title="{{ (products | filter: {brandId: detail.BrandId})[0].brandName}}"
            >
              <!-- default option when not preset by detail.ProductId-->
              <option value="">-- please choose brand --</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>{{detail.BrandId}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <hr/>
      <p>Product is predefined. So the brand is pre-selected by product. BUT: after brand is selected, the product-details do NOT change!</p>
    Selected <strong>detail</strong>:
      <pre ng-model="selected">{{detail | json}}</pre>
   </body>
</html>
```

### See also

For using **ng-options**, see also [plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ccsAVvPACnN6Qzje7HcB).

Comment: The select in my question is disabled because it's auto-selected whenever that user selects a product, that's where ProductId comes from.

Answer (score 1):

You can register the selected option object in the ng-repeat parent scope by using **as alias-expression** provided by ng-repeat.
In your case you just need to do something like that:

```
<select ng-model="detail.BrandId" 
        title="{{options | selectedProductFilter : detail.ProductId}}" 
        class="form-control" 
        disabled>
    <option ng-repeat="option in mainCtrl.products as options" 
            ng-selected="option.Id === detail.ProductId" 
            ng-value="option.BrandId">
        {{option.Brand.Name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

The options object will be available in your controller closure and you can display the title by using a custom filter.

```
angular.module("app").filter('selectedProductFilter',
    function () {
        return function (input, id) {
            if (!input) return "";
            let occurence = input.filter(function (x) {
                return x.Id == id;
            });
            return occurence.length > 0 ? occurence[0].Brand.Name: "";
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but 'selectedOption' would contain all of 'mainCtrl.products' not just the selected option.

Comment: You're right. Check out the filter usage. It's pretty clean in the view.

Comment: Thanks I never thought of using filters like this but it seems pretty heavy for just displaying the title. I'll consider using this though if I don't find a solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do `ng-change` event in your `select` and call function in it that change the value of label text to the select value name. something like below
In Html

```
ng-change="changedValue(detail.BrandId)"
```

In JS

```
$scope.changedValue = function(item) {
    //change label name here
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a suggested solution but as I indicated in my question I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use javascript.

Comment: you can change the label text you just need to bind the label with scope make your label like ```<label for="MyField">{{ myFieldLabel }}</label>``` and add this to change value function ```$scope.myFieldLabel = item;```

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for solution without the change function in JS.

Answer (score 0):

fill ng-model by "option" not "option.BrandId"

then you can set title like this :

mainCtrl.products['ng-model-name'].Brand.Name

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion however I do not wish to change the ng-model since BrandId is connected to my db.

Comment: for this you can use setter when ng-model sets , change the brandid

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could achive this:

```js
(function () {
 "use strict";
 const app = angular.module("app", []);
  
 app.controller("app.AppCtrl", $scope => {
    $scope.selectedOption = null;
    $scope.optionList = [{_id: 1, label: 'Option 1'}, {_id: 2, label: 'Option 2'}];
  });
  
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="app.AppCtrl">
 <select title="{{selectedOption.label}}" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedOption">
  <option ng-repeat="option in optionList" ng-value="option"> {{option.label}}</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to change the ng-model to 'detail.Brand'

Answer (score 0):

Try using **ng-init**,

add **ng-init** to your select tag and put your object index value you want to be selected by default.

e.g.
Your code

```
<select ng-model="detail.BrandId" title="" class="form-control" disabled>
    <option ng-repeat="option in mainCtrl.products" ng-selected="option.Id === detail.ProductId" ng-value="option.BrandId">{{option.Brand.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

adding following code (Suppose I want index 0 by index):

```
ng-init="detail.BrandId = option[0].Brand.Name"
```

It will look like this :

```
<select ng-model="detail.BrandId"  ng-init="detail.BrandId = option[0].Brand.Name" title="" class="form-control" disabled>
        <option ng-repeat="option in mainCtrl.products" ng-selected="option.Id === detail.ProductId" ng-value="option.BrandId">{{option.Brand.Name}}</option>
</select>
```

or Check these thread's

[how to use ng-option to set default value of select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329495/how-to-use-ng-option-to-set-default-value-of-select-element)

[How to set default value in ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993468/how-to-set-default-value-in-ng-options)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and link threads. I checked them but it didn't work for me.

Comment: any error you're getting or any other issues with the above code?

Comment: Selected is not always at index 0 and using ng-init changes the brandId. Thanks for your suggestion though.